# Strings in Embedded resource - Failed to access

Tags: .net-3.5, resources, embedded-resource, resx

I am using Visual Studio 2008, Framework 3.5 SP1. I have an assembly in which I have Strings.resx file. This file contains several strings. All over this assembly, I just get my strings back using "Strings.MyString" as it generates a CLR class. It compiles fine and no issues. But when I try to use this assembly in other solution, I get the following error "Provider type not defined. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090017)". None of my strings are accessible now.

Could some please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to answer my own question. The assembly in whihc I have my resx file, "NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute" attribute is set to "None". I changed it to "en-US" and everything started working.